# MongoDB Not Running from Command Prompt

Tags: python, mongodb

I am a newbie in Python and has installed MongoDB but each time I try to run mongo.exe from command prompt `C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin>mongo.exe`, it issues the following:

`MongoDB shell version: 2.6.3`

`connecting to: test`

`2014-07-15T10:02:02.670+0100 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reas
on: errno:10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively
refused it.`

`2014-07-15T10:02:02.672+0100 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (
127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed`

How can I resolve this? Thank you.

Comment: Are you running the mongod.exe in the background on your local machine? mongo.exe merely tries to connect to the actual database..

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you're running `mongod` in another terminal tab first.